# Running a shell command from perl and allowing interaction

Tags: perl

I need to be able to run a commandline command from my perl script and I want the user to be able to interact with it like normal.

For example, the script I want to run is `ssh $user@$box '. ./.profile 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && AnotherScript.pl'`
I want the user to be able to interact and see the ssh command just as if he/she had executed it themselves. I don't care what happens during the command, I just want execution passed back to my perl script when it's finished.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
system 'ssh', "$user\@$box", '. ./.profile 1>/dev/null 2>&1 && AnotherScript.pl';
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html for details about the built-in `system` function.

Comment: I'm interested in allowing my user to interact with the shh, and the command it executes. I want to hide sourcing .profile from the user because that's not important, however AnotherScript.pl is important.

Comment: @Malfist: Yeah, sorry, I was misreading. You posted your comment right as I was fixing my answer. :-)